# Protect Infura ID from being stolen and abused

Tags: ethers.js, security, infura, web3-providers

I'm using an Infura API key for my dApp's "Connect Wallet" integration with [Web3Modal](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal)

**Key:**

[image: Infura API Key]

**Relevant Codebase:**

```js
import Web3Modal from 'web3modal'
import WalletConnect from '@walletconnect/web3-provider'

...

    const modalInstance = new Web3Modal({
      network: 'mainnet',
      cacheProvider: false,
      providerOptions: {
        walletconnect: {
          package: WalletConnect,
          options: {
            infuraId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

Someone has been stealing this Infura API key everyday, by sniping it from my web app's javascript source code (which is of course client-side and impossible to prevent), and exploited the key for all request capacity they can get, forcing me to swap in a brand new infuraId on a daily basis.

How does one safeguard against this?

I'm playing around with the ORIGINS allowlist setting in the Infura dashboard but it doesn't seem to actually prevent requests from going through.

Many thanks!

Comment: Change your infura passwore, revoke your API key and create new one.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but I rather not do this everyday forever =D

Comment: I dont understand how they exploit your API key. Are you sure you are not making any call (perhaps scripts that you have makes more call than you calculate?

Comment: Are you familiar with how Web3Modal works? You pass it an INFURA ID. But it's on the front-end, and anyone can snipe it from the javascript source code.

Comment: Can you post the JS code where you use web3modals and infura?

Comment: Posted the JS code! As you can see the infuraId is in plain text, and I not sure how that's avoidable...